# How to scrape address (comma separated text) using p tag - BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to scrape address from the below link:

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/rollin-phatties-houston
```

But I am getting only the first value of the address (i.e.: `1731 Westheimer Rd`) out of complete address which is separated by a comma:

```
1731 Westheimer Rd, Houston, TX 77098
```

Can anyone help me out with this, please find my code below:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as url

source = url.urlopen('https://www.yelp.com/biz/rollin-phatties-houston')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

mains = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "secondaryAttributes__09f24__3db5x arrange-unit__09f24__1gZC1 border-color--default__09f24__R1nRO"})
main = mains[0] #First item of mains

address = []
for main in mains:
    try:       
        address.append(main.address.find("p").text)
    except:
        address.append("")

print(address)
# 1731 Westheimer Rd
```

I want the result from the p tag and below are the two p tag details:
Note: I want to append the address in a list.

```
<p class="lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--subtle__373c0__3DZpi text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-">1731 Westheimer Rd, Houston, TX 77098</p>


<p class="lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--semibold__373c0__2l0fe text-size--large__373c0__3t60B"><a class="lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__1G70M link-color--blue-dark__373c0__85-Nu link-size--inherit__373c0__1VFlE" href="/map/rollin-phatties-houston" target="" name="" rel="" role="link">Get Directions</a><p class="lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--subtle__373c0__3DZpi text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-">1731 Westheimer Rd, Houston, TX 77098</p></p>
```

For more details, you can refer to the link: `https://www.yelp.com/biz/rollin-phatties-houston`

Answer (score 2):

The page page is loaded dynamically, therefore `urllib.request` doesn't support it. However, the data is available in JSON format on the page, which you can search for using the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module, and extract it using the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

```
import re
import json
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request as url

source = url.urlopen("https://www.yelp.com/biz/rollin-phatties-houston")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

data = soup.select_one(
    "#wrap > div.main-content-wrap.main-content-wrap--full > yelp-react-root > script"
).string

json_data = json.loads(re.search(r"({.*})", data).group(1))

print(json_data["bizDetailsPageProps"]["bizContactInfoProps"]["businessAddress"])
```

Output:

```
1731 Westheimer Rd, Houston, TX 77098
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually, I want to append these in a list.
But, I am unable to append these in a list. Could you please help in this:


address = []
for main in mains:
    try:
        data = soup.select_one("#wrap > div.main-content-wrap.main-content-wrap--full > yelp-react-root > script").string
        json_data = json.loads(re.search(r"({.*})", data).group(1))
        new_data = json_data["bizDetailsPageProps"]["bizContactInfoProps"]["businessAddress"]
        address.append(new_data)
    except:
        address.append("")

Comment: @Goutam By me `mains` is empty. Not sure how you have it, maybe you have a typo in the post with the class-name?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please, find the GitHub link: https://github.com/goutamborthakur555/WebScraping-with-and-without-proxy/blob/master/Web_Scraping_Yelp_GB.py (I actually want the "business_address" details should consist of the entire address. Please help me out with this.)

Comment: @Goutam This is a completely new question. If this answer has solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted. And consider asking a new question here on SO.

Comment: Thank you. Let me post a new question.

Comment: I have posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375725/how-to-scrape-full-address-comma-separated-text-using-beautifulsoup-in-pytho